# iOS UIViewController inside a UIView

Tags: ios, swift3, uiviewcontroller

Please help me with this kind of setup.
How to do this?

**I checked other answers but this is different from others. Please do not flag as duplicate.**

I tried with `UIView` inside `UIView`. 
But I want to have a series of `UIViewController` transitions happen inside `UIView`.

[image]

Moderators: It is a single question : How to have a NavigationController inside a UIView. For explaining the scenario I gave an image. That is all. It is not a project that I have asked for. :) Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you need to use UINavigationController

Comment: You cannot have a UIViewController inside a UIView. It's vice versa.

Comment: But I can have UIViewController in Container. Can't I have Container in UIView?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the container depicted above: no. The "container" is just another UIView. Open Xcode, storyboard and add a new UIVisualEffectView. You'll see a UIView in there, being the "container" in the image. Maybe I can help you if you state what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: What you're describing in your diagram can be configured directly in Interface Builder, so it's a bit hard to see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

If this is what you wanted, you can add Container View inside your view and embed the ViewController that comes with the Container View in an UINavigationController.

[image]

Comment: That's great. I tried this. But the second viewcontroller is being presented instead of getting pushed. I have Navigation Controller on first one. Still when I tap on Push Next button, the next viewcontroller is presented.

Comment: This solved my problem. This is the right answer. Thanks Rikesh.

Answer (score 0):

[image]In your storyboard:

- Delete the UIViewController embedded by Container.
- Place new UINavigationController and link Container's 'viewDidLoad'
  to the UINavigationController's 'embed'.
- Delete the RootViewController of the UINavigationController's.
- Place new UIViewController and link UINavigationController's 'rootViewController' to the new UIViewController.

Comment: But when I present the viewcontroller that has container, also should have a visualeffectsview. When I present it, it would not show blur background even when I present that with current context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use child view controller.

Add a navigation controller's (Containing root view) view to view you want transition on.
Add navigation controller as child to top most active controller.
After that you can navigation inside UIView with this child navigation controller.

```
    let rootController:UIViewController = UIViewController.init();
    rootController.view.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 480);
    let navController:UINavigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: rootController);

    self.view.addSubview(navController.view);
    self.addChildViewController(navController);
```

Your container is self.view.
ViewController 2 is rootController inside navigation controller.
From ViewController 2 you can navigate anywhere with the help of navigation controller.